# Prevent site from redirecting to login URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, basic-authentication

I've developed a simple set of pages using ASP.NET MVC - then hosted them in IIS 7.5.
These are just visual pages with no data behind them.
The server is online and I didn't want the casual observer to be able to access them so simply set IIS up with basic authentication.  I then created a limited demo account so that I could send details to customers so they can take a look at these visual pages.

When going to the url:
www.myserver/mysite/home/index

The browsers username and password box pops up as I would expect.
I then type in the details for my demo account.

However after a succesful authentication rather being taken to 
www.myserver/mysite/home/index

My browser instead trys to take me to something along the lines of:
  www.myserver/mysite/home/index/login.aspx?ReturnURL=.....

If I then return to the original URL it loads correctly.
How can I prevent the redirect following the sucsesful login?

Comment: Since you are using HTTP basic authentication, have you disabled the Forms authentication in your application?

Comment: In the web config file I have the following:
<authentication mode="None">
</authentication>